# separating data frames instead of dropping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In python when using pandas, the similar rows can be dropped using `drop_duplicates`. Is there any way to separate the dataframe into two dataframes and not actually "drop" rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the dataframe by duplicates, maybe you could use the boolean array returned by`.duplicated()`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,3,2,4]})
>>> df
   A
0  1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  2
5  4

[6 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df_a, df_b= df[~df.duplicated()], df[df.duplicated()]
>>> df_a
   A
0  1
2  2
3  3
5  4

[4 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df_b
   A
1  1
4  2

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```